# How to merge duplicated property value and sum their other property - java

Tags: java

I have list of this object, wanted to sum duplicated item's contrast and remove duplicates.

```
public class ContrastItem {
    private String range;
    private Long contrast;
}
```

```
            [{
                "contrast": 3,
                "range": "00:00:00-00:59:59"
            },
            {
                "contrast": 1,
                "range": "00:00:00-00:59:59"
            },
            {
                "contrast": 0,
                "range": "01:00:00-01:59:59"
            },
            {
                "contrast": 0,
                "range": "01:00:00-01:59:59"
            }]
```

Expected:

```
            [{
                "contrast": 4,
                "range": "00:00:00-00:59:59"
            },
            {
                "contrast": 0,
                "range": "01:00:00-01:59:59"
            }]
```

I have tried stream mapping the list with groupby and summingLong but could't wrap around my head to solve it.(don't know what i'm doing)

```
mylist.stream()
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
ContrastItem::getRange,Collectors.summingLong(ContrastItem::getContrast)))
.entrySet().stream().map().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Show the code you wrote. If you are hitting a specific issue, we can help you better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is quite close,

```
itemList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy
        (
            ContrastItem::getRange,
            Collectors.summingLong(ContrastItem::getContrast)
        ));
```

this code creates a map `{01:00:00-01:59:59=0, 00:00:00-00:59:59=4}`

then you need to convert to ContrastItem list

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<ContrastItem> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
    itemList.add(new ContrastItem("00:00:00-00:59:59", 3L));
    itemList.add(new ContrastItem("00:00:00-00:59:59", 1L));
    itemList.add(new ContrastItem("01:00:00-01:59:59", 0L));
    itemList.add(new ContrastItem("01:00:00-01:59:59", 0L));

    List<ContrastItem> collect = itemList.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    ContrastItem::getRange,
                    Collectors.summingLong(ContrastItem::getContrast)))
            .entrySet().stream()
            .map(entry -> new ContrastItem(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(collect);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely do it with `Stream` and it looks not very complicated. `groupingBy + reducing` is what you need.

```java
Collection<ContrastItem> items = contrastItems.stream()
   .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
      ContrastItem::getRange,
      Collectors.reducing(new ContrastItem(0L, ""),
         (one, two) -> new ContrastItem(one.getContrast() + two.getContrast(),
                                        two.getRange()))))
   .values();
```